# open SweetAlertDialog in another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I have app with to Activities. I want that a `SweetAlertDialog` will open in the second Activity when I move from the first Activity to the second one.

So my question is how to open it when I move to another activity? Or how I open `SweetAlertDialog` without clicking on any buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do anything when an Activity starts is to do it in `onCreate()`. So just open the dialog in the second Activity's `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

On your second Activity, just show it on `onCreate()`

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // call your dialog here
        SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog();
        sweetDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want that a SweetAlertDialog will open in the second Activity when I move from the first Activity to the second one.

It's easy, you just need to create the `SweetAlertDialog` inside your **SecondActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ...

  new SweetAlertDialog(this)
         .setTitleText("Here's a message!")
         .show();
}
```

in case you don't always need to use the SweetAlertDialog, you can use a flag:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras != null) {
    boolean showDialog = extras.getBoolean("showDialog");
    if(showDialog) {
       new SweetAlertDialog(this)
             .setTitleText("Here's a message!")
             .show();
    }
  }

}
```

where you can start the SecondActivity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("showDialog", true);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

> So my question is how to open it when I move to another activity

If you want to always show the SweetAlertDialog whenever you change to the other Activity, you need to create the dialog inside `onResume`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  new SweetAlertDialog(this)
        .setTitleText("Here's a message!")
        .show();
}
```